# 3 different store from the same service

Tags: extjs, model, load, store

I use a json service for my grid. There are 3 grids where i use the same service. What i do now is load this service each time for the grids

```
storeGridEvents = new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'intern',
proxy: {
    url: storeUrl,
    reader: {
         type: 'json',
         root: 'data'
            }
        }
});

storeGridEventData = new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'dataEvents',
proxy: {
    url: storeUrl,
    reader: {
         type: 'json',
         root: 'data'
            }
        }
});

storeGridEventLocation = new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'locations',
proxy: {
    url: storeUrl,
    reader: {
         type: 'json',
         root: 'data'
            }
        }
});
```

Is there a way i load the service just once and use it for three models? That would save some loading time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load store once and then clone it so you will have two more local copies.

Update: here is example of simple cloning store function:

```
cloneStore: function(store, storeClass) {
  var new_st = Ext.create(storeClass),
      recs = [];

  store.each(function(r) { recs.push(r.copy)});
  new_st.add(recs);

  return new_st;
}
```

Comment: okay thanks. I can't find this in the extjs docs. Is there a function for it?

Comment: Not really. You need to create function yourself. Let me post some code.